# if else conditions problems

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

> Hi,I have some problems in this function.
>
> I want to create a carousel/slider with five div,on-click of the left arrow the first div move to left of -336px but the next div (box 2) on-click don't move.
>
> to left, I don't know why the conditions isn't verified.

```
    <div class="test">
    <div id="box1" class="box_img" style="background:black">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" />      
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box_img" style="background:black">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" />      
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box_img" style="background:black">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" />      
    </div>
    <div id="box4" class="box_img" style="background:black">
        <img src="images/4c .jpg" />        
    </div>
    <div id="box5" class="box_img" style="background:black">
        <img src="images/5.png" />      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow" id="arrow_left">
    <img src="images/arrow_right.png" />
</div>
<div class="arrow" id="arrow_right">
    <img src="images/arrow_left.png" />
</div>
```

```
    function Slide(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.box_img").each(function(i){
            var firstBox = $("#box1");
            var secondBox = $("#box2");
            var thirdBox = $("#box3");
            var fourthBox = $("#box4");
            var fifthBox = $("#box5");
        $("#arrow_left").on({
            click:function(){

                if(i=1){
                    firstBox.animate({"margin-left":"-336px"},400); 
                    //return(i<2);
                }
                else if(i=2){
                    secondBox.animate({"margin-left":"-336px"},400);
                    //return(i<3);  
                }
                else if(i=3){
                    thirdBox.animate({"margin-left":"-336px"},400);
                    //return (i<4);
                }
                else if(i=4){
                    fourthBox.animate({"margin-left":"-336px"},400);
                    //return (i<5);
                }
                else if(i=5){
                    fiftheBox.animate({"margin-left":"-336px"},400);    
                    //return (i<6);
                }else{
                    alert("else finale");
                };      
            }//end click fn
        }) //end on
        console.log(i);
        })//end each
    })
};
```

Comment: `i=1` is an assignment. `i==1` or `i===1` would be a comparison

Comment: if(i=4){?? Do you know what that does?? This condition will always be true, and it will ASSIGN i=4. So mayby start with if (i === 4)

Comment: the way you're using that each statement seems a bit odd.

Comment: yes Felk ,i have correct the operator = with == . I'm testing the conditions for animate the div box one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` to compare. You are now using the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks Barry,i have correct this error but know all the div move to left on the first click...i will find a method for move one div at a time and not all together..